# Jquery picking elements from dynamic table

Tags: jquery, html-table, underscore.js

I have a table template which is populated by data sent from server in JSON format. The code for template is as follows:

```
<table id="mangeDataTable" class="tablesorter">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th >S.No</th>
                    <th >Manga</th>
                    <th >Status</th>
                    <th > Edit</th>
                    <th> Delete</th>

             </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% for (var i = 0; i < mangaData.length; i++) { %> <% var item =mangaData[i]; %>
            <% var count=i%>

                <tr>
                <td><%= ++count%></td>
                <td><%= item.text%></td>
                <td><%= item.status%></td>
                <input id="mangaName" type="hidden" name="text" value="<%= item.text%>"/>
                <td><a href="#edit-box"  class="edit-window" title="<%= item.text%>" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="#delete-box"  class="delete-window" title="<%= item.text%>" >Delete</a></td>

            </tr>
             <% } %>
             </tbody>
        </table>
```

Using the above template, I am able to create a table like in the image below:
[image: MangaDatatable]

**The problem is in the edit & delete functionality**. I want the data of the row (manga name, status) to be picked on click of edit/delete. Until now, I have been setting the name into the title attribute of anchor tag and extracting it through jquery att().

```
var mangaName=$(this).attr("title");
```

But this is not the way to do things. It was only a temporary solution I opted. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rikesh,

jQuery's `.closest()` is your best friend here.

```
$('#mangeDataTable').on('click', '.edit-window', function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var mangaName = row.find('td').eq(1).text();
    //then do whatever is necessary to edit
}).on('click', '.delete-window', function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var mangaName = row.find('td').eq(1).text();
    //then do whatever is necessary to delete
});
```

The floating `<input>` inside a `<tr>` but not in a `<td>` is probably not a good idea. It's uncertain how browsers will handle this and I'm guessing the element will be unaddressable in at least some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already use jQuery, I'd suggest you use the datatables plugin to display and edit your data.  It's relatively easy to setup and use.

Main page: http://datatables.net/examples/

With an example matching your description here:
http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/inlineControls.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I came across such plugins during my research. But for now I want to use a simple table. Isn't it possible to somehow pic the values adjacent to edit/delete?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the title in a data attribute on the `<tr>` and then [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find it. Your HTML template would look like this:

```
<tr data-title="<%= item.text %>">
    <!--...-->
</tr>
```

Then your edit and delete handlers could find the title like this:

```
var title = $(this).closest('tr').data('title');
// Or even $(this).closest('[data-title]').data('title') for more future-proofing
```

Then you could use the `title` attributes on the edit and delete links for their intended purpose (i.e. to give the user a little extra information about what the link does):

```
<td>
    <a ... title="Edit <%= item.text%>">Edit</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a ... title="Delete <%= item.text%>" >Delete</a>
</td>
```